# Create a table using a list of elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a list of elements that changes regularly and instead of displaying them in a list format (one list element per line) I'd like to display this in a table/grid format (3-4 elements per line).

What's the best way to do this using `haml` or `erb`?  I'm using bootstrap as well so if there's an easy way to do this using that framework, it might be nice.

Comment: @locoboy- Are you talking about something like this? 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#tables

Comment: yes but it has to be dynamic since the list size keeps changing.

Comment: let's say that you have an array of things you want to show in a table. How would you format the view such that as you go through the array it will populate a table not a list of items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with Haml and Bootstrap (two different versions). The Ruby `each_slice` method does the hard work.

I have Continent and Country models. On the Continent page, I display all of the countries for a given continent in a table. The number of columns in the table is defined in a model method in the Continent model.

continents_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @continent = Continent.find(params[:id])
  @country_rows = Country.where(:continent_id => params[:id]).map {|c| c.name}.each_slice(Continent.number_of_table_columns).to_a
  ...
end
```

Haml:

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    %table.table
      %tbody
        - @country_rows.each do |country_row|
          %tr
            - country_row.each do |country|
              %td= country
```

continent.rb:

```
class Continent < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    def self.number_of_table_columns
      4
    end
end
```

Html output (sample):

```
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <table class='table'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Spratly Islands</td>
            <td>Vietnam</td>
            <td>Azerbaijan</td>
            <td>Georgia</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sri Lanka</td>
            <td>Israel</td>
            <td>Cyprus</td>
            <td>Yemen</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Maldives</td>
            <td>Kuwait</td>
            <td>West Malaysia</td>
            <td>Nepal</td>
          </tr>
          ...
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's another alternative that is more convenient because the Country objects can be accessed in the view:

continents_controller.rb (2nd version):

```
def show
  @continent = Continent.find(params[:id])
  @country_rows_2 = Country.where(:continent_id => params[:id]).each_slice(Continent.number_of_table_columns)
  ...
end
```

Haml (2nd version):

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    %table.table
      %tbody
        - @country_rows_2.each do |country_row_2|
          %tr
            - country_row_2.each do |country_2|
              %td= country_2.name
```